# how to call dll written in foxpro from oracle stored procedure?

Tags: linux, oracle

i installed oracle11g in OEL5.9.
i need to call a DLL written in FOXPRO from one of my stored procedures.
i tried this code:

```
create or replace function test (x pls_integer,     
                                 y  pls_integer    
                                 )

Return pls_integer  

IS EXTERNAL  

Name "t_dll"    

LIBRARY newtest 

LANGUAGE C     


PARAMETERS (x long,   

            y long, 

            return long);
```

but it raised this error:

```
ora-06522 invalid elf header
```

i understood that LINUX uses SO files instead of DLL.
now i want to know how can i convert DLL to SO?
 does external procedures work just for c and java?
if yes,so how can i call FOXPRO procedures in oracle?
any one can help me?
thanks in advace

Comment: Not really an Oracle question; [possibly a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1641585/266304)? Do you have a source code?

Comment: You can't just "convert" a dll to run on another OS without all the supporting DLLs.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes i have foxpro source code